# Error 'Could not determine java version from ‘10’

Tags: react-native, genymotion, native-base

`npm run android` is not working.

- node version: v8.9.4
- npm version: 5.7.1
- genymotion: 2.12.0

I'm getting the error:

> Could not determine java version from ‘10’

I don't have have an Android Studio installed, but I have installed Gradle 4.6, and also set the path for Java, created `JAVA_HOME` and set path for genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

Revert back the java version to 8*. Android does not support 9 or above, yet.

Comment: Thanks for this. I already deprecated my java version to 8 and it works.

Comment: Wow really?? I hope Jave multiple environment tools